# Add image in using css

Tags: html, css

I have following code to display the image in button using CSS, but I am unable to get it working. The image is in the same directory where the CSS file is.

```
#submit-go {
  margin-top:1em;
  width:69px;
  height:26px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:0;
  background:url(submit-button.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer !important; cursor:hand;
}

#submit-go:hover {
  background-position:0 -26px;
}
```

```
<div align="center"><button type="submit" id="submit-go" >Submit</button></div>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? `align` is also a deprecated attribute

Comment: I would advise you to style buttons with CSS as much as possible and preferably without background images. Take a look at CSS3 gradients, border radius, box shadow, text shadow.

Comment: Try creating a Fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/ ) and givin' us the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because `background` is still overriding `background-position`. Try changing `background` to this:

```
#submit-go {
  margin-top:1em;
  width:69px;
  height:26px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:0;
  background-image:url(submit-button.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer !important; cursor:hand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/rDvTe/1/ and think it works properly tested in Chrome).

I replaced the image link with a URL so it would work, and also added

```
#submit-go {border: 1px solid red;}
```

to better see the button.

Am I right if I suppose you wanted the background-image to show up on hover? Else just switch the background-position in normal and hover state. 
Hope this is what you were looking for.